# Why is there no review link in the top-bar

Tags: feature-request, review

I can cast close and reopen votes in the review queue. But there is no link to that queue in the top-bar.

Can this be added?

Answer (score 6):

[You need 350 rep to be granted the access to the review queue.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

For a private beta site, voting to close and reopen is a privilege granted to everyone. But this will quickly change once the site gets out into public beta. When you get 350 rep, you should be able to get the review link at the top bar.

Comment: You can by-pass that by adding `/review` at the end of `softwarerecs.stackexchange.com`.